# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.4.0

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abdulsamadgroup.com.asgroup"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.3'

}
```

and [here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmz7u.png) details of installed sdk i am using.

Help me solve this problem. I have been searching it from 2 days.

Comment: 24.2.0 or 24.4.0 ?

Comment: try with latest buildtool(buildToolsVersion "25.0.0") and appcompact('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update your Support Repository** .

**1st way**

Set

```
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

And

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Gradle** .

**2nd way**

You can use latest version,

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

And

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

Comment: @ManXoor Restart your IDE and Gradle once again

Comment: @ManXoor did't find `v7:24.4.0` in your gradle section first . Make sure, you gradle whole project

Comment: i mean sync your project .`File->Synchronize`

Answer (score 1):

Try change `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'` to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.4.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Please update you JDk version .
For Updating `23.0.0` JDK version is `1.7`.
If you wanted to update more `24.0.0` or `25.0.1` your JDK version should be `1.8`.

```
Error:Buildtools 25.0.1 requires Java 1.8 or above.  Current JDK version is 1.7.
```